# Generating higher quality/less 'fuzzy' Venn diagrams with eulerr

Tags: r, eulerr

I am trying to generate a high-resolution Venn diagram. I have used package eulerr. When I run the following code:

```
library(eulerr)

VennDiag <- euler(c("Drug and alcohol services" = 312, "Mental health services" = 380, 
                    "Drug and alcohol services&Mental health services" = 116))

plot(VennDiag, quantities = list(type = "counts", fontsize=13.5), 
     labels = list(cex=1.2, alpha=0.7, labels=c("Drug and alcohol\n services", "Mental health\n services")), 
     fills= list(fill=c("#004e72", "#27a2db"), alpha=0.7), main = "", edges=list(lex=1.5))
```

I get the following output:
[image]

Is there a possibility to modify this so the edges are less pixelated/fuzzy?

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly are you saving the image? Are you using the RGUI or RStudio? What OS are you on?

Comment: RStudio. Windows. Just realised that adding `tiff("test1.tiff", units="in", width=7, height=5, res=700)` at the beginning and `dev.off()` at the end fixes it

Comment: Realize that tiff, png, and jpg are all "raster" (pixel-based) images, so the only way to improve quality for them is to increase the size and/or DPI. The best quality images will be in a "vector"-based format, usually PDF or SVG (EMF, a windows/ms-office centric format, is also vector-based).